# Set class to IEnumerable and get type

Tags: c#, asp.net

Been searching and trying different things but just can't seem to get it working right.
So, here are the basics...

```
namespace Model
{
  [Serializable]
  public class SomeMDL : IEnumerable<string>
  {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public int Volumne { get; set; }
      public int Size { get; set; }
  }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return ID.ToString();
        yield return Volume.ToString();
        yield return Size.ToString();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then call the class:

```
        Model.SomeMDL mdl = new Model.SomeMDL();
        mdl.ID = 1;
        mdl.Volume = 2;
        mdl.Size = 2;

        string myVar;            
        foreach (string item in mdl)
        {                
            //myVar = item.GetType().ToString();
            //myVar = item.GetEnumerator().GetType().Name.ToString();
            //myVar = item.GetEnumerator().GetType().FullName.ToString();
            //myVar = item.GetEnumerator().GetType().DeclaringType.FullName.ToString(); //null ref
            myVar= item.ToString(); //gets the value             
        }
```

What I am looking for is a way not only to bring back the values, which is item.ToString() but I need to know which public int it is reading. Is it ID, Volume, or Size?
Need to bring back a string of the type (ID, Volume, or Size).

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do with your `foreach` loop?  Then we could suggest another way to achieve what you want, because implementing `IEnumerable` doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missed something about your code here, it seems like you're misusing/misunderstanding the basic concept of the `IEnumerable` interface. `IEnumerable` is used to represent a group of objects of the same type, which can then be iterated through. All you're doing is just yielding each of the properties within your class - what is the point? If you need any one of the properties, why not just access it normally? What do you imagine you'll gain by allowing yourself and others to blindly iterate through your three properties?

Comment: First, there is a reason I need that value or I wouldn't be doing this at all. And second, since you didn't answer the question directly, I take it as you don't know the answer.

Comment: @Zath. There's a reason you need which value, specifically? I am answering the question directly - there's not going to be a way to tell which property you're accessing at any point in the enumeration because that's not how IEnumerables work. The entire concept is that they're just a group of values to be iterated over, not that you should be able to say, "oh, this one corresponds to that property in the containing class." If you want to go far outside the scope of how everyone else uses something, you'll need to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, I have 10 separate Model's to iterate through and place in a database. So, placing all items in a dataset and using a User Defined Table Type to insert/update the database is the best way to go instead of adding 100 parameters for the stored procedure.

Comment: So why not iterate through an `IEnumerable` containing all 10 models, then do whatever you need with each models' `ID`, `Volume`, and `Size` properties within your `foreach` loop?